# Using python to connect processes stdin/stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a bash script (fifo1 and fifo2 are created with mkfifo):

```
processor <fifo1 >fifo2 &
source >fifo1 &
sink <fifo2 &
```

which realizes the graph:

```
source -> processor -> sink
```

How would I go about doing this in a python script ?

Comment: Is there anything special about your script that requires named pipes, instead of `source | processor | sink`?

Comment: @chepner  This is an asynchronous system where source can yield data at any time (of indeterminate length). And the system should run until "killed". It strikes me as the `source | processor | sink` construction does not lend itself exactly to this, but I might be wrong. I'll investigate that.

Answer (score -1):

To play with system processes you can use [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#) and [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Then to share data between processes you can use [PIPE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.PIPE).

Example codes are also provided [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-examples)

Here is a simple implementation:

p1.py

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'temp2.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()

print('\nStdout value' + repr(stdout_value) + '\n')
print('\nStderr value' + repr(stderr_value) + '\n')
```

This code will call **temp2.py** program then
temp2.py

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                        , stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdin_value, stdout_value = proc.communicate()
print('\nStdin value' + repr(stdin_value) + '\n')
print('\nStdout value' + repr(stdout_value) + '\n')
```

The **temp2.py** will then execute `ls` command in your current directory and then save the result.

To get more details of how to use the stored value from pipes check [this](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#connecting-segments-of-a-pipe) there are many variation to use system input output and it depends on your implementation so check the above docs for further help.